# Cisco : How to route a single server IP which is already in a routed nerwork

Tags: exception, routes, range, ip, cisco

Just a simple question, it is possible to route a single IP to the default route when this IP is in a range that is already routed.

I have to route this whole range to a certain IP : 10.0.0.0/8
This range goes from 10.0.0.1 to 10.255.255.254

The fact is that we are connected trough a VPN to a server with the IP 10.173.90.171.

Can I make my switch route every IP on the range 10.0.0.0/8 except the single IP 10.173.90.171 and make it go to the default route ?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You just need to add this specific prefix and point it to the desired gateway. In basic IP networks, routing decision is always performed on most specific entry (10.173.90.171/32). This way you can have `10.0.0.0/8` routed via `192.168.0.1` and then `10.173.90.171/32` routed via `172.16.0.1`.

Comment: Just tried it ! Works like a charm thank you